# How to turn a df (x,y,z) into a table using the columns x and y as labels and fill the cells with a function including z?

Tags: r

My data frame is made up of three columns called "vehicle", "age" and "ways" like this:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 3
  vehicle     age   ways
   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1     4        25 0.201
 2     1        24 0.216
 3     4        25 0.236
 4     4        25 0.147
 5     4        24 0.435
 6     4        25 2.54 
 7     1        24 0.268
 8     1        25 0.194
 9     4        23 0.360
10     1        26 0.248
11     5        24 0.239
12     2        26 0.162
13     4        23 2.15 
14     1        25 0.554
15     4        26 0.384
16     3        26 0.122
17     4        27 0.183
18     4        25 1.36 
19     4        25 1.27 
20     1        24 0.404
21     2        27 0.479
22     1        25 4.98 
23     3        25 0.113
24     4        25 0.297
25     4        24 0.566
26     4        24 1.12 
27     4        25 0.394
28     4        25 2.77 
29     4        24 4.63 
30     4        24 0.677
```

I want to transform this data frame into a table with the column
"vehicle" as vertical labels and the column "age" as horizontal labels.
Which would look something like this:

```
vehicle/age|  23 | 24 | 25 | 26 ...
-----------------------------------
     1     |     |    |    |
–----------------------------------
     2     |     |    |    |
-----------------------------------
     3     |     |    |    |
-----------------------------------
     4     |     |    |    |
```

And I want to fill the unfilled cells with a mathematical function like this:

Example:

```
cell1 = ((∑ ways of vehicle 1 and age 23)*100) / (∑ all ways of all vehicle with age 23)
```

I know a way how I can do this manually with using some filter, group_by and summarize functions and writing the single results into excel.
I am just curious if there is a better and faster way because i need to this with more data frames.

For everyone who is willing to find a solution for my problem,
thank you very much!

Comment: Check out the gather() and spread() functions in the tidyr package.

Comment: Hi, can you post your data with `dput this makes it easier to work with it.
Also it would be good if you can post your desired output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xtabs`, as already shown by @jay.sf, in combination with `prop.table` like:

```
prop.table(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D)) * 100
```

In case you want to show the percentages per column you can use:

```
prop.table(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D), 2) * 100
```

Since *R 4.0.0* you should use `proportions` instead of `prop.table` which makes

```
proportions(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D)) * 100
```

and

```
proportions(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D), 2) * 100
proportions(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D), "age") * 100 #Alternative
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work for me.
Nevertheless, could you explain to me what the 2 in prop.table(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D), 2) * 100 does? I simply do not understand why the 2 makes all the difference.

Comment: The 2 defines the margin, what says give the proportions per column.

Answer (score 1):

With `xtabs()`.

```
res <- xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D) / sum(D$ways) * 100
res
#        age
# vehicle         23         24         25         26         27
#       1  0.0000000  3.2058919 20.6794469  0.8953392  0.0000000
#       2  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.5848587  1.7293043
#       3  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.4079570  0.4404491  0.0000000
#       4  9.0616990 26.8168526 33.2683490  1.3863316  0.6606737
#       5  0.0000000  0.8628470  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
```

Do e.g. `res <- data.frame(unclass(res))` to get a `"data.frame"` from the `"table"` object. You also may round, e.g. `round(res, 2)`.

#### Data

```
D <- structure(list(vehicle = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), age = c(25L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 24L, 
25L, 23L, 26L, 24L, 26L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 
27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L), ways = c(0.201, 
0.216, 0.236, 0.147, 0.435, 2.54, 0.268, 0.194, 0.36, 0.248, 
0.239, 0.162, 2.15, 0.554, 0.384, 0.122, 0.183, 1.36, 1.27, 0.404, 
0.479, 4.98, 0.113, 0.297, 0.566, 1.12, 0.394, 2.77, 4.63, 0.677
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Looks like he wants `xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D) * 100 / sum(D$ways)` or `prop.table(xtabs(ways ~ vehicle + age, D)) * 100`

Comment: @GKi True. Your suggestion also saves the `aggregate()`, thanks!

Comment: @GKi your solution seems like the right way. I realized that i made a mistake in my example function cell1= ...
Is there a way to use your functions you stated above and divide them by the sum of all the ways of all vehicle of the specific age (e.g. age 23)?
As an example:
You would divide the sum of the ways for vehicle 1 and age 23 by all the ways of the age 23 column.
And this for every cell of every column. But in the column age 24 you would divide by the sum of all the ways in the column age 24.

Answer (score 1):

**Data thanks to jay.sf - Edit: I added vehicle == 1 & age == 23:**

```r
D <- structure(list(vehicle = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,1L), age = c(25L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 24L, 
25L, 23L, 26L, 24L, 26L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 
27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L,23L), ways = c(0.201, 
0.216, 0.236, 0.147, 0.435, 2.54, 0.268, 0.194, 0.36, 0.248, 
0.239, 0.162, 2.15, 0.554, 0.384, 0.122, 0.183, 1.36, 1.27, 0.404, 
0.479, 4.98, 0.113, 0.297, 0.566, 1.12, 0.394, 2.77, 4.63, 0.677, 0.55
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Solution:**

```r
D %>%
  group_by(vehicle,age) %>%
  summarise(ways = sum(ways)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(age,ways) %>%
  gather(age,ways,-vehicle) %>%
  mutate(ways = case_when(is.na(ways) ~ ways[age == 23 & vehicle == 1]*100/sum(ways, na.rm = TRUE), TRUE ~ ways)) %>%
  spread(age,ways)
```

Edit:

I updated the code to reflect the fill function based on what I understood it to be.

Comment: The data frame which I provided is just a sample of my original data frame with 316361 rows, so this sample does not provide every possible outcome.
"∑ ways of vehicle 1 and age 23" should be the sum of all the ways the persons who are age == 23 and use vehicle == 1 have covered.
So "∑ ways of vehicle 1 and age 23" is a bad example because the result is not provided by my shown data frame. Please excuse this.

Question:Is it the mean*100/sum(total) of ways for the relevant row OR column?
Answer: Of the column.

Comment: @C.Toni I updated the data and solution to show how it would look like if the age==23&vehicle==1 case is present and the basis of the fill function. IF I understood your fill function correctly, otherwise it should still be easily adaptable.

Comment: I think I did not explain my function correctly.
"∑ ways of vehicle 1 and age 23" was just an example. I would like this for every cell individually. Like:
The cell of vehicle 1 and age 23 to be "(∑ ways of vehicle 1 and age 23)*100 / ∑ all the ways of age 23 with all vehicles".
The cell of vehicle 2 and age 23 to be "(∑ ways of vehicle 2 and age 23)*100 / ∑ all the ways of age 23 with all vehicles".
And so on until all the cells of age 23 are filled.

Comment: Then I want this for the age 24 as well. Like:
The cell of vehicle 1 and age 24 to be "(∑ ways of vehicle 1 and age 24)*100 / ∑ all the ways of age 24 with all vehicles". Until all cells of the age 24 are filled.
And the same for age 25, 26 ...

I hope you can understand what I am trying to say.
I am very sorry for the inconvenience.